# ConTeXt: What is the default value for \setuphead[title][after={...}]

Tags: context

I'd like to revert to the standard spacing for `title` mid-document, after I've set a custom spacing with `\setuphead[title][after={\blank[1cm]}]`. How can I read out the value before setting it?

On a side note: Where in the conTeXt source code are the values for the standard document class coded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `\showrootvalues` and in your case the `\showinstancevalues` command to display the default values. Here's an example:

```
\usemodule [setups]
\starttext
  %% show \setuphead values for all instances
  %% \showrootvalues[head]

  %% show \setuphead values for the title instance
  \showinstancevalues[head][title]
\stoptext
```

[image: example]

Comment: You're back!  It's been almost two years.